# PHP Weird Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: php-7

When defining an Array of Objects, I obtain a

> Trying to get property of non-object

on some nested attributes of my initial object.

Here is the code used:

```
$res = [];
foreach($data as $el) {
    //dd($el->rel->anotherProp); // string(2) "ok"
    $res[] = [
        'foo' => $el->foo,
        'bar' => $el->bar,
        'anotherProp' => $el->rel->anotherProp, // Trying to get property of non-object BUT $el->rel['anotherProp'] works
    ];
}
```

Ran with PHP 7.0.16.

Is a matter of some sort of scope in PHP?

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: Well, I use Lumen and the $data is a Eloquent iterable Collection. The stack trace is quite long. Do you want the first chunk to avoid visual pollution?

Comment: what $data , please attach full code